# Explain 2D array iteration with 1 loop

Tags: c++, c++11

Can someone explain why this algorithm works for iterating a 2D array as a 1D array? In other words.. with one loop?

```
const int Width = 6;
const int Height = 4;

int Array[Width][Height];

for (int I = 0; I < Width * Height; ++I)
{
    Array[I % Width][I / Width] = I; //This line :S
}

for (int I = 0; I < Height; ++I)
{
    for (int J = 0; J < Width; ++J)
    {
        std::cout<<Array[J][I]<<"  ";
    }
    std::cout<<"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way to see how it works is to plug in the numbers yourself. Starting from 0, we'll get:

```
Array[0 % 6][0 / 6] = Array[0][0]
Array[1 % 6][1 / 6] = Array[1][0]
...
Array[5 % 6][5 / 6] = Array[5][0]
Array[6 % 6][6 / 6] = Array[0][1]
...
Array[11 % 6][11 / 6] = Array[5][1]
```

and so on. Because it uses integer division, each time we go through `Width` values, it `i / Width` will be one more. Utilizing `i % Width`, this will then loop over each value (in this case, 0 to 5) at that specific `i / Width`. Because integer division truncates, this will be the same until `i` becomes the next multiple of `Width`.

Comment: I understand you explanation :) Are there downsides to this vs. the two for-loops?

Comment: Yes. Firstly, it uses a modulo and a division for each loop value, which can be expensive operations - for a large loop, this may add quite a bit of overhead. Secondly, it's slightly obfuscated compared to just doing two loops.

Comment: This is pretty amazing how it works. Thanks for a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using it as a 1D array.  You are still indexing it as a 2D array.  However, you're using maths (modulo and integer division) to recover the 2D indices from a 1D index based on the array's dimensions.  This is pretty normal, but it's unusual to do this in a loop the way you've done so, as it could be computationally expensive.

Comment: Why would it be expensive? Wouldn't two for-loops be the same?
Wow.. That loop! I've never seen a loop like that. But that loop changes the order of the numbers. That one is column major and the other was row major

Comment: Yeah, forget my loop... It was column-major.  The reason it's expensive is you're doing a whole lot of modulo and division and recalculating both values every time, whereas with nested loops you're just iterating.

Comment: But the guy @Mattingly's post says it automatically does the math for me so wouldn't it be the same then?

Comment: Yes, but you're doing that *as well as* the modulo and division.  Whether this actually happens will depend on the compiler's optimization smarts, but I prefer not to put my faith in that.  If you're keen on a column-major array that's actually laid out in memory as a column-major array, have a look at an old answer of mine  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778377/get-the-first-column-of-a-matrix-represented-by-a-vector-of-vectors/15799557#15799557).  It's row-major, but easily modified to column-major.  If you're going to do mostly column-major operations, maybe consider it.

Answer (score 1):

The memory allocated for a 2 dimensional array is still laid out linearly.  So if you were to examine the memory at your variable *Array*, it would consist of **Width** number of *ints* followed by **Width** number of *ints* again... for **Height** times.

If **Width** = 5, and **Height** = 2... the memory for *Array* would look something like this (where each [] set is an integer):

[w0/h0][w1/h0][w2/h0][w3/h0][w4/h0][w0/h1][w1/h1][w2/h1][w3/h1][w4/h1]

When you use *Array[j][i]* to access the array, it's just automatically doing that math for you, to offset correctly into the linear block of memory.

Comment: Right... I meant to mention that getting rid of the modulo and divide in the single loop method (and replacing it with just '[I]') would result in the same output with improved performance.

Answer (score 1):

`for (int x = 1, y = 1; y <= 5; (x < 5) ? (x++) : (x = 1, y++))`

I'm sorry.