# C how to move through 2 dimensional array based on address

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through a 2 dimensional array as a single dimensional array.  Since a 2 dimensional array will occupy continuous memory, is there a way to address the two dimensional array as a single dimensional array by changing the index by 4 bytes.  I'm assuming an integer array.  Could some one provide an example?  I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    for (int j = 0;j < 2; j++){
        z[i][j] = count;
        count++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%d\n", z[i]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explain 2D array iteration with 1 loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976328/explain-2d-array-iteration-with-1-loop)

Comment: Just use the first subarray... eg. for `int arr[3][3]` index `arr[0]` from `arr[0][0]` to `arr[0][8]`... or use an `int *`, eg: `int *p = arr[0];` and use `p[0]` ... `p[8]`

Comment: [example](http://ideone.com/qDXQhT)

Comment: Dmitri, your comment doesn't make any sense.  How can you access arr[0][8] when it's declared [3][3]?

Comment: The suggested duplicate is not good; that is using a complicated scheme to access the 2D array with 2 subscripts, whereas this seeks to access a 2D array with 1 subscript (unless I'm misunderstanding the code).

Comment: @DCR: Dmitri's suggestion is correct.  `p` is declared as an `int *` — not as a 3x3 array.

Comment: his second part is correct but this eg. for int arr[3][3] index arr[0] from arr[0][0] to arr[0][8]  doesn't make any sense

Comment: @BLUEPIXY your example is great.  thanks.  Isn't there a way to just move the memory address inside the index?  p[? + (i*4)]

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) for(int j = 0; j < 2; ++j) p[i * 2 + j]` ?

Comment: sort of but i thought there was a way to express the move or offset as 4 bytes at a time

Comment: It is not necessary to multiply the index of the array(or  pointer to `int`) by the offset (`sizeof(int)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2D arrays can be iterated through in a single loop like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[2][2], *p;
    a[0][0] = 100;
    a[0][1] = 200;
    a[1][0] = 300;
    a[1][1] = 400;

    p = &a[0][0];

    while(p!=&a[0][4])
        printf("%d\n", *p++);

    return 0;
}
```

Remember that an array index is just an offset from the first element of the array, so there is no real difference between `a[0][3]` and `a[1][1]` - they both refer to the same memory location.

Comment: how can that possibly be right a[0][3] and a[1][1] hold different values.  in fact, based on your example a[0][3] is out of bounds while a[1][1] stores 400.  Oh, they are both 4 places offset.  and int[][] is almost an *

Answer (score 0):

Access 2D arrays like this

```
int *array;   // note one level of pointer indirection
array = malloc(width * height * sizeof(int));  / allocate buffer somehow

for(y=0;y<height;y++)
  for(x=0;x<width;x++)
    array[y*width+x] = 0; // address the element by calculation
```

In three dimensions

```
  int *array;   // note one level of pointer indirection
  array = malloc(width * height * depth * sizeof(int));  / allocate buffer somehow

 for(z=0;z<depth;z++)
   for(y=0;y<height;y++)
     for(x=0;x<width;x++)
       array[z*width*height + y*width+x] = 0; // address the element by calculation
```

Generally it's easier to use flat buffers than to mess around with C and C++ convoluted rules for multi-dimensional arrays. You can also of course
iterate through the entire array with a single index. If you want to set 
up a 2D array, then cast the array to a  single pointer, it behaves the
same way.

```
     #define HEIGHT 50
     #define WIDTH 90
     int array2D[HEIGHT][WIDTH}:

     int * array = reinterpret_cast<int *>(array2D):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>   

int arr[4][3]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9},{10,11,12}};


void my_fun(int(*a)[],int m,int n)
{

for(int i=0;i<m*n;i++)
 {
   printf("%d\n",(*a)[i]);
 }

}

int main()
{

  my_fun(arr,3,4);

 return 0;

}
```