# creating matrix using 2-d vector c++

Tags: c++

im trying to explain the problem i have. 
I need a 2-d matrix which contains 233x233 row and columns.

```
for(int  i  =  0; i < dimension;i++)
   for(int  j  = 0 ; j < dimension;j++)


     distance3 = sqrt(pow((apointCollection2[j].x - apointCollection[i].x1), 2) + pow((apointCollection2[j].y - apointCollection[i].y1), 2));
        if (distance3 < Min)
        {
            Min = distance3;
            station = busStation;

        }
        distance2 = sqrt(pow((apointCollection2[j].x - apointCollection[i].x2), 2) + pow((apointCollection2[j].y - apointCollection[i].y2), 2));
        if (distance2 < Min2)
        {
            Min2 = distance2;
            station1 = busStation;

        }
```

So i find the minimum distance and two stations with minimum distance. The first station(station) corresponds to row and the second one (station1) corresponds to column. Then i need to increment the number of people these(can be called route) has.

Then i need to find the station and station1 after the second iteration and if they are the same i need just to increment people and not add the same stations to the vector.

Or another variant i thought 
I creat a 2-d vector with 233x233 and 0 values in each cell.

```
vector< vector<int> > m;
cout << "Filling matrix with test numbers.";
m.resize(233);  
for (int i = 0; i < 233; i++)
{
    m[i].resize(233); 
    for (int j = 0; j < 233; j++)
    {

    }
}
```

After the loop above i decided to create the following where i find the min distance :
Here  i want to increment somehow:

```
m[station][station1] = person;
    if (find(m.begin(), m.end(), station, station1))
    {
        person++;
    }
    else
    {
        m[station][station1] = person;
    }
```

I have an error in "find" because there is no instance of function template.Another problem i don't add values to vector but here also a mistake when i want to add.

This should be done very easy just need to find out the logic i should follow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Find might be easier if you treat your 2D matrix as a 1D matrix.

Comment: Use single vector to keep a matrix. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15799557/3344612) an example of the implementation. This will make your life easier.

Comment: btw, pow(x, 2) is much much slower than x*x

Comment: @Exceptyon You have any source on that? I was pretty sure the compiler simplified that away.

Comment: @JonathanMee http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71bcf654940d654d shows about 5x slower, ofc depends on compiler and optimizations

Comment: @Exceptyon So this is interesting. I copy your code into Visual Studio 2015 and run in release, the times vary slightly, sometimes `x * x` is faster, sometimes `pow(x, 2)` is faster. But on gcc even with -O3 `x * x` is always faster. I guess that optimization only happens on Visual Studio :(

Comment: If you want us to be able to help with this problem you need to explain what `apointCollection2[j].x` and `apointCollection[j].x1` are, cause what it initially sounded like was that you were trying to recreate the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), but now I don't think that is it, but I have no idea what this is...

Comment: Nope TSP problem , i know how to create it and it isnt the same. I just need to create a matrix where already are 233x233 rows and colums ( each column and each row represent stations). When i find the min distance , i need to increment in the rigth cell the number of people and. That's it.  What you ask me is just coordinates

Comment: As a side note: `std::vector<std::vector<int> > m(233, std::vector<int>(233));` will create your matrix of desired dimensions with no additional resizing.