# C++ using vector<vector> to represent matrix with continuous data buffer

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, vector, malloc

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<float>> func(int M)
{
    // res = matrix size MxM
    vector<vector<float>> res;
    float* buffer = static_cast<float*>(malloc(M * M * sizeof(float)));
    res.reserve(M);
    for (int i=0; i<M; i++) {
        res.emplace_back(buffer + i * M, buffer + (i + 1) * M);
        /// res[i] = compute_the_matrix();
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

I'm required to make a function that use `vector<vector<float>>` to represent a matrix. However, it's inefficient because the rows might be at different location in memory, while a good matrix should have all its element in a continuous block.

To do this, I `malloc` a continuous block of memory. Then initialize the vectors from this block.

Is this method safe and will the vectors free memory correctly when it's destructed? Another situation I can think of is if there's an exception in `res[i] = compute_the_matrix();`, then we have a memory leak.

**Edit:** I think this code perform copy-constructor instead of move-constructor, so it's not what I'm looking for. So, how can I make a vector that is continuous in memory?

Comment: I don't know what you think you're doing here, but this function will allocate `M` vectors of length `M` which have no guarantee about memory contiguity relative to one-another, and you initialize them with uninitialized data that you allocated with `malloc`, then you leak that memory before returning the vectors. A better approach is to avoid using vector-of-vector altogether. Use a single vector and wrap it in a simple class that you can then use to access the data. You can even use array-like operator overloads to make it feel more familiar.

Comment: Yes I've noticed and pointed that out in the edit. I wish the buffers of these `M` vectors to be continuous in memory. Is there any way to achieve this? I'm aware that avoiding vector-of-vector is the best solution, but using `vector<vector>` is a requirement constraint

Comment: The only way to make the buffers of a vector-of-vector contiguous is to use a custom allocator, but then you'll wind up in a whole new and horrible scenario that can be avoided if you just use a better data type to begin with.

Comment: @HuyLe It is impossible then.

Comment: Check out an [answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15799557/1553090) a while ago, also in response to someone's vector-of-vector question. This shows you how to make a contiguous data structure for a MxN matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't do what you think it does.

The line

```
res.emplace_back(buffer + i * M, buffer + (i + 1) * M);
```

creates a new `std::vector<float>` to add to `res`. This `std::vector<float>` will allocate its own memory to hold a copy of the data in the range `[buffer + i * M, buffer + (i + 1) * M)`, which also causes undefined behavior because you never initialized the data in this range.

So, in the end you are not using the memory you obtained with `malloc` at all for the vectors. That memory is simply leaked at the end of the function.

---

You can't specify what memory a `vector<vector<float>>` should use at all. There is simply no way to modify its allocation strategy. What you can do is etiher use a `vector<float>` instead to hold the matrix entries linearly indexed in a single vector or you can use a `vector<vector<float, Alloc1>, Alloc2>` where `Alloc1` and `Alloc2` are some custom allocator types for which you somehow specify the allocation behavior so that the storage layout is closer to what you want (although I doubt that the latter can be done nicely here or is worth the effort over just using the linear representation).

Comment: Hmm then I guess this requirement is impossible. I know the correct solution, just wondering if this one also works. Thanks